# Tengo este error : error you have an error in your sql syntax check the

Tags: c#, mysql

estaba configurando una de mi formulario donde le estaba agregando el boton buscar el cua al indicarle una ide me cargara los datos del paciente a todo my texbox , al realizar los código y al ejecutarlo , todo marcha bien hasta el momento cuando deseaba guardar los datos de mi formulario cita me sale lo siguiente, me gustaría que me ayudaran y me dijeran de que proviene este error.

error you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the syntax to use near')at Line 1

Este es mi Código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Consultorio_Clinico
{
    public partial class Citas : Form
    {
        public Citas()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
         MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=localHost;DataBase=consulta_clinica;Uid=1234;pwd=polo123;");
         MySqlCommand comando;
         MySqlDataReader mdr;

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conectar.Open();

            string selectQuery = "select * from paciente where id_pacient=" + int.Parse(txtbuscarnom.Text);
            comando = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conectar);
            mdr = comando.ExecuteReader();

            if (mdr.Read())
            {
                txtidpacient.Text = mdr.GetString("id_pacient");
                txtnompacient.Text = mdr.GetString("nom_pacient");
                txtedapacient.Text = mdr.GetInt32("ed_pacient").ToString();
                txttelpacient.Text = mdr.GetString("tel_pacient");
                txtdirpacient.Text = mdr.GetString("dir_pacient");
                txtciudpacient.Text = mdr.GetString("ciud_pacient");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No existen datos para esta ID");
            }
            conectar.Close();
             txtbuscarnom.Clear();
        }

        private void btnbuscardoct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conectar.Open();

            string selectQuery = "select * from medico where id_doct=" + int.Parse(txtbuscardoct.Text);
            comando = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conectar);
            mdr = comando.ExecuteReader();

            if (mdr.Read())
            {
                txtiddoct.Text = mdr.GetString("id_doct");
                txtnomdoct.Text = mdr.GetString("nom_doct");
                txtespecdoct.Text = mdr.GetString ("espec_doct");

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No existen datos para esta ID");
            }
            conectar.Close();
            txtbuscardoct.Clear();
        }

        private void txtbuscarnom_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                conectar.Open();
                MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("insert into cita values('" + txtidpacient.Text + "','" + txtnompacient.Text + "','" + txtedapacient.Text + "','" + txttelpacient.Text + "','" + txtdirpacient.Text + "','" + txtciudpacient.Text + "','" + dateTimefecha.Text + "','" + txtprecpacient.Text + "','" + txtiddoct.Text + "','" + txtnomdoct.Text + "','" + txtespecdoct.Text + "',)", conectar);
                comando.ExecuteReader();

                MessageBox.Show("Registro guardado con exito");
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error.." + error.Message);
            }
                conectar.Close();
                txtidpacient.Clear();
                txtnompacient.Clear();
                txtedapacient.Clear();
                txttelpacient.Clear();
                txtdirpacient.Clear();
                txtciudpacient.Clear();
                txtprecpacient.Clear();
                txtiddoct.Clear();
                txtnomdoct.Clear();
                txtespecdoct.Clear();
                txtbuscarnom.Clear();
                txtbuscardoct.Clear();

            }
    }
}
```

[image: Esa es mi Formularios - les pido que me ayuden , necesito saber cual es my error]

Comment: Al final de tu insert tienes una coma demás `"',)"`

Comment: Gracias , Pero ahora me salio el siguiente Error : error..Column cout does't match values cout at row 1

Comment: Cuando haces `insert` sin especificar las columnas, debes de incluír todas las columnas de la tabla dentro de `values()` al igual que ponerlas en el orden correcto de las mismas. Probablemente no estés incluyendo todas las columnas en el insert, de ser así tienes de dos: Ingresar todas las columnas en `values()` aunque pongas valores nulos, o especificar las columnas después de `insert into table`

Comment: Gracias a Todos por la ayuda que me dieron , Descubri que mi error al principio con la ayuda de @Lixus , que era por una coma demás , después el otro error era por el orden de los campos que tenias en Insert , lo tenia mal ordenado, Le agradezco bastante a todos por su ayuda , También , Espero que continúen ayudandomes

Comment: Gracias a Todos por la ayuda que me dieron .

Answer (score 2):

en primer lugar evita insertar directamente los valores, envialos como parametros a fin de evitar inyeccion de codigo, en segundo lugar la estructura de la instruccion insert esta mal, debes especificar los campos y en tercer lugar usar un "executeNonQuery" en vez del "executeReader"

Aqui un ejemplo de codigo para algo similar

```
comando.Parameters.Clear();
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campo1", campo1);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campo2", campo2);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campo3", campo3);
comando.CommandText = "insert into tabla (campo1,campo2,campo3) values ("@campo1,@campo2,@campo3)";
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu error esta en el Insert porque le estas diciendo que valores debe de insertar en cita pero no le estas especificando en que parte la vas a guardar, el codigo que te adjunto es uno de una BD que tengo en el cual guardo los textbox en la tabla tool y en su parte correspondiente.

```
                Connet.Open();
                SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("Insert into Tools(ID_Tool,Station,Model,Operation,Dynamic_T,Dynamic_T2,Dynamic_T3,Estatic_T,Category,Generation,Tool_Type,Service_Kit,Protective_Cover,Cover_Socket,Controller,Version,IP_Adress,Tool_Name,ToolsNet,Active_in_Net,Nodo,Stack_Light,Brand,No_Replacement_Tool,Husillos,Tool_Range,No_Tool_series,Calibration_Pattern,Tool_Description,Calibration_Frequency,Master_Transducer,Add_Reason,Reason_Leaving,Last_Certification,Next_Certification,Responsable_Certification,instructions,No_Review,Date_Review,Date_Issue,Date,Area_Responsable,Operator,Area,Turn,week,month,Precision,Monitoring,Tool_Calibration_last_Date,Tool_Calibration_Next_Date,Torquimetro_Check_Time,Torquimetro) Values('" + txtidtool.Text + "','" + txtstation.Text + "','" + txtmodel.Text + "','" + txtoperation.Text + "','" + txtTdynamic.Text + "','" + txtTdynamic2.Text + "','" + txtTdynamic3.Text + "','" + txtTstatic.Text + "','" + txtcategory.Text + "','" + txtgeneration.Text + "','" + txttyp.Text + "','" + txtkitservice.Text + "','" + txtprotective.Text + "','" + txtcoversocket.Text + "','" + txtcontroller.Text + "','" + txtvertion.Text + "','" + txtip.Text + "','" + txttoolname.Text + "','" + txttoolsnet.Text + "','" + txtnet.Text + "','" + txtnodo.Text + "','" + txtstack.Text + "','" + txtbrand.Text + "','" + txtnotoolsreplacement.Text + "','" + txthusillo.Text + "','" + txttoolrank.Text + "','" + txtserialtool.Text + "','" + txtcalibration2.Text + "','" + txtobservation.Text + "','" + txtfrecuency.Text + "','" + txtmaster.Text + "','" + txtregister.Text + "','" + txtregister2.Text + "','" + txtlastcertification.Text + "','" + txtnextcertification.Text + "','" + txtcertificationresponsable.Text + "','" + txtinstruction.Text + "','" + txtnoreview.Text + "','" + txtreview2.Text + "','" + txtemission.Text + "','" + txtdate1.Text + "','" + txtresponsable.Text + "','" + txtoperator.Text + "','" + txtarea.Text + "','" + txtturn.Text + "','" + txtweek.Text + "','" + txtmonth.Text + "','" + txtprecision.Text + "','" + txtmonitoreo.Text + "','" + txtlastdatecalibration.Text + "','" + txtnextdatecalibration.Text + "','" + txttorquimetrochecktime.Text + "','" + txttorquimetro.Text + "');", Connet);
                insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Connet.Close();
```

Comment: Cuando un insert se hace sin especificar columnas se puede hacer siempre y cuando en los valores incluyas todas las columnas y en el orden en que van, el código que tiene sin especificar columnas puede funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Lo comentaba porque era lo unico diferente que yo veia de todo el codigo que yo tengo. Pero pues a la mejor es otra cosa. Suerte!

Comment: Yo me lo encuentro extraño un poco por yo tengo una form Usuario que no le especifico donde lo devo guardar y me lu guarda de una vez a mi base de datos , mira esto: